# Stream APP ZegoCloud Easy Example Web turn to Audio Only

Tags: java, web, video-streaming, audio-streaming, zegocloud

I'm very new to **java** and need to **customize** one Example of [ThisGit](https://github.com/ZEGOCLOUD/easy_example_web/blob/main/README.md)

**The Example above shows the Web Communication with Video, but I need to turn it to Audio**

This must be done by edit Join ROOM function:

Everything I'm trying shows errors ... Maybe someone can help

When you want to communicate with audio and video, you need to call the join room interface first. According to your business scenario, you can set different audio and video controls through options, such as:

> ZegoMediaOptions enumeration can be found in
> src/ZegoExpressManager.entity.ts.

```
 export enum ZegoMediaOptions {
  AutoPlayAudio = 1,
  AutoPlayVideo = 2,
  PublishLocalAudio = 4,
  PublishLocalVideo = 8,
}
```

> **call scene**: [ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayVideo,
> ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio, ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalAudio,
> ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalVideo], **the default is this scenario Live**

```
ZegoExpressManager.shared.joinRoom(config.roomID, token, { userID: config.userID, userName: config.userName });
```

> **scene - host:** [ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayVideo,
> ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio, ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalAudio,
> ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalVideo]
> **Live scene -**
> audience:[ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayVideo,
> ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio]

> **Chat room - host:**
> [ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio, ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalAudio]

> **Chat room - audience:** [ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio]

**This is what i Try:**

```
    ZegoExpressManager.shared.joinRoom(config.roomID, tokenObj.token, {
        userID: config.userID,
        userName: config.userName,
 AutoPlayAudio: 1,
AutoPublishAudio: 4,
      });
```

*EDIT* **That tried piece above is not showing any errors anymore! But it still PUBLISH Video**

Comment: please share the error stacktrace

Comment: The last thing I Tried showing no Errors anymore but its still not Works, i mean it does still Publish Video....

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

**ZegoCloud** Team told me how to do it and I feel dumb now:

```
 ZegoExpressManager.shared.joinRoom(config.roomID, tokenObj.token, {
        userID: config.userID,
        userName: config.userName},[1,4]);
```